# vb.net отправка письма с помощью Thunderbird

Tags: .net, vb.net

Пытаюсь программно отправить письмо через `Thunderbird`.

Первая проблема, не получается добавить параметр `format=html`, для отправки сообщения ввиде `html`. Второе, не понимаю как нажать на кнопку "отправить", что бы оно отправилась а не просто открылось окно с самим емейлом.

Смотрел тут документацию по параметрам: http://kb.mozillazine.org/Command_line_arguments_-_Thunderbird

Мой код:

```
Dim strTO As String = "testEmail@testEmail.com"
Shell("""C:\Program Files (x86)\Mozilla Thunderbird\thunderbird.exe"" -compose ""mailto:" & strTO & "?subject=" & b_MailInfo.DTA.Betreff.Value.ToString & "&body=" & b_MailInfo.DTA.Text.Value.ToString & """")
```

С `HTML` решил... осталось понять как нажать кнопку "отправить"

```
Shell("C:\Program Files (x86)\Mozilla Thunderbird\thunderbird.exe -compose" &
                      " preselectid='id1'" &
                      ",to='ilja.grebel@atx-hardware.de'" &
                      ",cc=''" &
                      ",bcc=''" &
                      ",newsgroups=''" &
                      ",subject=" & b_MailInfo.DTA.Betreff.Value.ToString &
                      ",body='" & b_MailInfo.DTA.Text.Value.ToString & "'" &
                      ",type='0'" &
                      ",format='1'" &
                      ",originalMsg=''" &
                      "")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Решил свою проблему следующим действием.

Мы открывает с помощью `Shell Thunderbird` и передаем ему все нужные нам данные, кому `Email`, его текст и тд и тп. Далее, нам нудно отловить наше открытое окно и нажать виртуально кнопки `CTRL+ENTER` (отправка письма). На всякий случай, у меня добавлен таймер, для того чтобы при открытии окна и передачи всех данных, у программы хватало времени на отправку.

```
Static start As Single
Static seconds As Single = 2

Private Declare Function FindWindow Lib "user32.dll" Alias "FindWindowA" (ByVal lpClassName As String, ByVal lpWindowName As String) As IntPtr
Private Declare Function SetForegroundWindow Lib "user32.dll" (ByVal hwnd As IntPtr) As Int32
Private HWND As IntPtr
```

---

```
Shell("C:\Program Files (x86)\Mozilla Thunderbird\thunderbird.exe -compose" &
                      " preselectid='id1'" &
                      ",to=" & EMAIL_TO &
                      ", newsgroups =''" &
                      ",subject=" & EMAIL_SUBJECT &
                      ",body='" & EMAIL_BODY_TEXT & "'" &
                      ",type='0'" &
                      ",format='1'" &
                      ",originalMsg=''" &
                      "")
HWND= FindWindow(vbNullString, "Verfassen: " & b_MailInfo.DTA.Betreff.Value.ToString & " - Thunderbird")
SetForegroundWindow(HWND)

start = VB.Timer()
Do While VB.Timer() < start + seconds
  System.Windows.Forms.Application.DoEvents()
Loop

SendKeys.Send("^{ENTER}")
```